# awk to find min and max of an array

Tags: arrays, for-loop, awk

I have file that generates different IDs and count as shown below

```
prod1 13
prod4 14
prod5 14
prod3 11
prod2 8
prod1 9
prod3 16
prod5 11
prod2 9
prod4 11
prod1 16
prod5 8
prod3 16
prod2 3
prod4 1
prod3 3
prod2 1
prod1 1
prod5 3
prod1 2
prod4 78
```

I am trying to find an option to get the max and min for each product.

Running the following awk script gives me the count and sum but I also need to track the min and max for each product.

```
awk '{ Prod[$1]++; sum[$1]+=$2 } END{ for (var in Prod) print var, "count", Prod[var], "and sum", sum[var]}'

prod1 count 5 and sum 41
prod2 count 4 and sum 21
prod3 count 4 and sum 46
prod4 count 4 and sum 104
prod5 count 4 and sum 36
```

Is there a way to modify the awk array script to get the max and min values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  awk '{Prod[$1]++
    sum[$1]+=$2
    min[$1]=Prod[$1]==1||min[$1]>$2?$2:min[$1]
    max[$1]=max[$1]<$2?$2:max[$1]} 
    END{ for (var in Prod) printf "%s count %d and sum %d max %d min %d\n", var,Prod[var],sum[var],max[var],min[var]}' file
```

gives

```
prod4 count 4 and sum 104 max 78 min 1
prod5 count 4 and sum 36 max 14 min 3
prod1 count 5 and sum 41 max 16 min 1
prod2 count 4 and sum 21 max 9 min 1
prod3 count 4 and sum 46 max 16 min 3
```

Comment: Could you explain how is this line working? `min[$1]=Prod[$1]==1||min[$1]>$2?$2:min[$1]` I guess is something equivalent to `min[$1]=(Prod[$1]==1||min[$1]>$2?$2:min[$1])`, but I still don't understand how Prod[$1]==1 is working. Much appreciated!

Comment: @manolius it is `min[$1]=booleanCHK?$2:min[$1]` the booleanCHK is `Prod[$1]==1||min[$1]>$2` if we translate it into English, it would be: "If the product is the first occurrence or Min(prod) is greater than the current value ($2)"

Comment: Of course! I just got it. I initialize the variable, that's why I don't need that "first occurrence". You are brave and confident working without parenthesis for operator precedence :-)   Thank you for your answer after so many years

Comment: @manolius if we write production codes, I would use parenthesis to make it easier to read or even comments, to tell what it does.